Access index 0 of array that has numbered keys starting at unknown values
I have an object that is generated in php that looks something like:
Object { 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…} etc..}

It is sent from the backend to the vue.js frontend, where it's iterated through and put into some charts.
I have a filter set up that filters based on content within the objects, but I'm having an issue with the keys that the objects are sent with. As soon as I filter, any loops that I have that require using the indices of the objects to access them break.
For example, say I have a loop like:
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.data).length; i++) {
   return this.data[i]; //or whatever
}

Because the backend sends the data with preexisting numbered keys, if the filter results in a set of objects that are no longer numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc but are instead something like 3,5,6,8 then the loops will break because it will look for index [0] and not find it.
What's the best way to handle this in javascript? Can I strip the object of the keys? Or ignore the keys and still look for this.data[0] in some way that ignores the numbered keys?

The solution is in your question, you can simply use Object.keys() to iterate over the keys, regardless of their type:
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
   console.log(this.data[key]);
});

If you want to keep using a similar syntax, use the following instead:
for (const key in this.data) {
    console.log(this.data[key]);
}


Change your for loop to a foreach loop
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
   return this.data[key]; // or whatever
});

